# How fast does the water have to go?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, speed

I have a pot of water. There is a one-way filter at the bottom right:

[image: Jug with on way filter]

How fast would the water have to be travelling to go into the tank via the one-way filter?

Also, I would like to have some sort of formula that allows me to work out how fast the water would have to be travelling in relation to the speed of the water entering and how much water is in the tank already.

Comment: Is the water going _in_ or coming _out_ of the valve? If you are trying to fill from the bottom, you need pressure, not velocity.

Comment: No the water is going into the tank

Comment: There is no minimum speed.

Comment: What do you mean @BillN

Comment: See Floris's answer. Speed is no the important parameter. Pressure is important. You could have a speed of 1 nanometer per second with the right pressure, or 5 m/s.

Comment: @BillN: and at 1 nm/s your flow speed into the tank is also basically zero. You're neglecting kinetic energy already held by the incoming water. Incoming speed, pressure and height are the factors. You're plain wrong and don't understand basic fluid mechanics.

Comment: @Gert I accept the points of your first 3 sentences.  Your last sentence is inappropriate, unnecessary, and incorrect.

Comment: @BillN: where you wrote: "Speed is no [sic] the important parameter" you were plain wrong. Fact.

Comment: Sorry guys. I have edited the question and I have unticked the answer that was wrong. I am looking for a proper answer now. Thanks. @Gert

Comment: Well, I've reinstated my original answer. See what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Tank problem.]

Ignoring drag and viscosity and assuming the one way filter puts up no resistance to flow in the 'open' direction, use [Bernoulli's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle#Incompressible_flow_equation):

$$\frac{v_1^2}{2}+gz_1+\frac{p_1}{\rho}=\frac{v_2^2}{2}+gz_2+\frac{p_2}{\rho}$$

Here, $z_1=0$ and $p_2=p_0$, where $p_0$ is *atmospheric pressure*, and $z_2=z$ (general case), then it follows that:

$$\frac{v_1^2}{2}+\frac{p_1}{\rho}=\frac{v_2^2}{2}+gz+\frac{p_0}{\rho}$$

$$v_2(z)=\sqrt{2\Big(\frac{v_1^2}{2}+\frac{p_1-p_0}{\rho}-gz\Big)}$$

Note that $v_2$ is a function of $z$: the higher the level of water in the receiving tank, the lower $v_2$ is, *all other things being equal*. Also, $v_2$ increases with $p_1$, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Can't really answer the question "how fast..." because that's the wrong parameter to focus on.

To force water into the inlet, you need *pressure* greater than $\rho g h$ where $\rho$ is the density of the water (1000 kg/m$^3$ for pure water at 20 °C), $g$ the acceleration due to gravity (9.8 m/s$^2$), and $h$ the height difference between the surface of the water and the inlet of the valve. Velocity doesn't come into it.

Comment: How fast would the water have to hit the valve to go through it? @Floris

Comment: It can be as slowly as you want... or are you saying you are aiming a free jet of water at the hole? Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I mean the water falls through the one-way filter into the water container. How fast will the water need to be falling to go into the water container @Floris

Comment: @Floris: why is it the "wrong parameter to focus on"? The flow speed *into* the tank definitely depends on it.

Comment: @Gert That wasn't the question.  It's a poor question. And to open the valve?? That depends on the valve model number. that's not a physics question.

Comment: @BillN: Sorry. Disagree. Wrong answer being rewarded here. It happens.